# BINARY_CHECKSUM - different result depending on number of rows

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I wonder why the [`BINARY_CHECKSUM`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/binary-checksum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) function returns different result for the same:

```
SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL),
            (3, 1, 2)) s(id,a,b);

SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL)) s(id,a,b);
```

Ouput:

```
+-----+----+------+-------------+
| id  | a  |  b   |     bc      |
+-----+----+------+-------------+
|  1  |    | 100  |        -109 |
|  2  |    |      | -2147483640 |
|  3  | 1  |   2  |          18 |
+-----+----+------+-------------+

-- -109 vs 100
+-----+----+------+------------+
| id  | a  |  b   |     bc     |
+-----+----+------+------------+
|  1  |    | 100  |        100 |
|  2  |    |      | 2147483647 |
+-----+----+------+------------+
```

---

And for second sample I get what I would anticipate:

```
SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, 1, 100),
            (2, 3, 4),
            (3,1,1)) s(id,a,b);

SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, 1, 100),
            (2, 3, 4)) s(id,a,b);
```

Ouptut for both first two rows:

```
+-----+----+------+-----+
| id  | a  |  b   | bc  |
+-----+----+------+-----+
|  1  | 1  | 100  | 116 |
|  2  | 3  |   4  |  52 |
+-----+----+------+-----+
```

**[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=7aeb37bb808cdc3e06a08c9298eaf9e5)**

---

It has strange consequences when I want to compare two tables/queries:

```
WITH t AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id, NULL AS a, 100 b
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL, NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 1, 2           -- comment this out
), s AS (
  SELECT 1 AS id ,100 AS a, NULL as b
  UNION ALL SELECT 2, NULL, NULL
  UNION ALL SELECT 3, 2, 1           -- comment this out
)
SELECT t.*,s.*
  ,BINARY_CHECKSUM(t.a, t.b) AS bc_t, BINARY_CHECKSUM(s.a, s.b) AS bc_s
FROM t
JOIN s
  ON s.id = t.id
WHERE BINARY_CHECKSUM(t.a, t.b) = BINARY_CHECKSUM(s.a, s.b);
```

**[db<>fiddle demo2](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdcddf454d7e88511cc2d48a06a9dd6e)**

For 3 rows I get single result:

```
+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+--------------+-------------+
| id  | a  | b  | id  | a  | b  |    bc_t      |    bc_s     |
+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+--------------+-------------+
|  2  |    |    |  2  |    |    | -2147483640  | -2147483640 |
+-----+----+----+-----+----+----+--------------+-------------+
```

but for 2 rows I get also id = 1:

```
+-----+----+------+-----+------+----+-------------+------------+
| id  | a  |  b   | id  |  a   | b  |    bc_t     |    bc_s    |
+-----+----+------+-----+------+----+-------------+------------+
|  1  |    | 100  |  1  | 100  |    |        100  |        100 |
|  2  |    |      |  2  |      |    | 2147483647  | 2147483647 |
+-----+----+------+-----+------+----+-------------+------------+
```

Remarks:

- I am not searching for alternatives like(HASH_BYTES/MD5/CHECKSUM)
- I am aware that `BINARY_CHECKSUM` could lead to collisions(two different calls produce the same output) here scenario is a bit different

> For this definition, we say that null values, of a specified type,
>   compare as equal values. If at least one of the values in the
>   expression list changes, the expression checksum can also change.
>   However, this is not guaranteed. Therefore, to detect whether values
>   have changed, we recommend use of BINARY_CHECKSUM only if your
>   application can tolerate an occasional missed change.

It is strange for me that **hash function returns different result for the same input arguments**.
Is this behaviour by design or it is some kind of glitch?

**EDIT:**

As [@scsimon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6167855/scsimon)
 points out it works for materialized tables but not for cte. 
**[db<>fiddle actual table](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e53d7e9d72cda6e2cb11878c3be9a2e)**

Metadata for cte:

```
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL),
            (3, 1, 2)) s(id,a,b)', NULL,0);

SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL)) s(id,a,b)', NULL,0)

-- working workaround
SELECT name, system_type_name
FROM sys.dm_exec_describe_first_result_set('
SELECT *
FROM (VALUES(1, cast(NULL as int), 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL)) s(id,a,b)', NULL,0)
```

For all cases all columns are `INT` but with explicit `CAST` it behaves as it should.

**[db<>fidde metadata](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=916abf7f96fb7f36421a31846bd50dd1)**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This has nothing to do with the number of rows.  It is because the values in one of the columns of the 2-row version are always `NULL`.  The default type of `NULL` is `int` and the default type of a numeric constant (of this length) is `int`, so these should be comparable.  But from a `values()` derived table, these are (apparently) not exactly the same type.

In particular, a column with only typeless `NULL`s from a derived table is not comparable, so it is excluded from the binary checksum calculation.  This does not occur in a real table, because all columns have types.

The rest of the answer illustrates what is happening.

The code behaves as expected with type conversions:

```
SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a, b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, cast(NULL as int), 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL)
     ) s(id,a,b);
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=2b092e5de1dea4d26f9528dde3b01c75) is a db<>fiddle.

Actually creating tables with the values suggests that columns with only `NULL` values have exactly the same type as columns with explicit numbers.  That suggests that the original code should work.  But an explicit cast also fixes the problem.  Very strange.

This is really, really strange.  Consider the following:

```
select v.*, checksum(a, b), checksum(c,b)
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100, NULL),
            (2, 1, 2, 1.0)
     ) v(id, a, b, c);
```

The change in type for "d" affects the `binary_checksum()` for the second row, but not for the first.

This is my conclusion.  When all the values in a column are binary, then `binary_checksum()` is aware of this and the column is in the category of "noncomparable data type".  The checksum is then based on the remaining columns.

You can validate this by seeing the error when you run:

```
select v.*, binary_checksum(a)
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100, NULL),
            (2, NULL,    2,   1.0)
     ) v(    id,a,    b,   c);
```

It complains:

> Argument data type NULL is invalid for argument 1 of checksum function.

Ironically, this is *not* a problem if you save the results into a table and use `binary_checksum()`.  The issue appears to be some interaction with `values()` and data types -- but something that is not immediately obvious in the `information_schema.columns` table.

The happyish news is that the code should work on tables, even if it does not work on `values()` generated derived tables -- as [this](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=6022c8a1ad2ae72f933da5aa2cd138af) SQL Fiddle demonstrates.

I also learned that a column filled with `NULL`s really is typeless.  The assignment of the `int` data type in a `select into` seems to happen when the table is being defined.  The "typeless" type is converted to an `int`.

Comment: In SQL Server default type for NULL is INT. It is a good observation

Comment: This doesn't happen when you use an [actual table oddly](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=9e53d7e9d72cda6e2cb11878c3be9a2e) with int datatypes so +1

Comment: Datatypes for all cases **[demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=0e587d128152cb522e103c1bd31c964b)** As I thouht all ints - so it looks like a glitch for me

Comment: @scsimon . . . I am perplexed.  According to the information schema tables, the types are exactly the same for all `NULL` values and when there is a number constant.  However, the `cast()` works in this example.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thank you for your insight Gordon. I will definitely return to this in 2019.

Answer (score 4):

For the literal `NULL` without the `CAST` (and without any typed values in the column) it entirely ignores it and just gives you the same result as `BINARY_CHECKSUM(b)`.

This seems to happen very early on. The initial tree representation output from

```
SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a,b) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100),
            (2, NULL, NULL)) s(id,a,b)
OPTION (RECOMPILE, QUERYTRACEON 8605, QUERYTRACEON 3604);
```

Already shows that it has decided to just use one column as input to the function

```
ScaOp_Intrinsic binary_checksum

    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Union1008
```

This compares with the following output for your first query

```
ScaOp_Intrinsic binary_checksum

    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Union1011 

    ScaOp_Identifier COL: Union1010
```

If you try and get the `BINARY_CHECKSUM` with

```
SELECT *, BINARY_CHECKSUM(a) AS bc
FROM (VALUES(1, NULL, 100)) s(id,a,b)
```

It gives the error

> Msg 8184, Level 16, State 1, Line 8 Error in binarychecksum. There are
>   no comparable columns in the binarychecksum input.

This is not the only place where an untyped `NULL` constant is treated differently from an explicitly typed one.

Another case is

```
SELECT COALESCE(CAST(NULL AS INT),CAST(NULL AS INT))
```

vs

```
SELECT COALESCE(NULL,NULL)
```

I'd err on the side of "glitch" in this case rather than "by design" though as the columns from the derived table are supposed to be `int` before they get to the checksum function.

```
SELECT COALESCE(a,b)
FROM (VALUES(NULL, NULL)) s(a,b)
```

**Does** work as expected without this glitch.

Comment: Good catch with `COALESCE`